# What is the difference between static computation and dynamic computation in MPI?

Tags: c++, c, static, parallel-processing, mpi

I have been asked to write two *MPI* programs in c: one that computes **statically** and one that computes **dynamically**.

The objective is to find the integral of an equation (let's say f(x) = x for simplicity) over a given interval using the box method. The problem is simple enough, I just have no clue what my professor means by static computation and dynamic computation.

I should probably add that it has been requested that I use the Master-Worker (otherwise known as Master/Slave) model.

Comment: *I just have no clue what my professor means*  Best ask your professor, surely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what this "static" versus "dynamic" computation means in the context of MPI. But since it has been asked to use some master/slave approach, I guess that the "static" version might be *business as usual*, while the "dynamic" one might imply the use of `MPI_Comm_spawn()` as described in the [dynamic process model](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf#section.10.2) chapter of the MPI standard.

That said, I find appalling that Master/Slave approaches, which are quite a niche for actual effective MPI parallelisations, are put forward so strongly in many MPI learning curricula. Indeed, I refer you to [my thoughts about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558591/5239503) which I wrote a while ago after having answered to too many Master/Slave oriented SO questions.

Comment: This may not be *precisely* the right answer, but it is about as close as you could get with the amount of info I offered (I wasn't very familiar with MPI at the time I posted the question). Thanks for your help!